# Exporting x,y,z coordinates from tracking information

Tags: animation, coordinates

I am new to blender and am trying to extract the coordinates of a moving object that was made in blender (X,Y,Z at every frame). I have tried exporting as .ply, .obj, .stl etc. but the coordinates don't seem to match the video of the moving animated object. I was told that this data can be extracted through the Python console, so I was wondering if there is a way to do this. Attached is a picture of the "coordinate map" that I would essentially like to extract and match.

Thank you !! [image]

Comment: Could you elaborate a little more? What do you mean by "extract the coordinates"? Do you want a list of (x,y,z) locations of the part for every frame? And what do you mean by "exporting as .ply, .obj, .stl etc."?

Comment: You won't get 3d information until you solve the motion for the object or the camera. For that you would need at least 8 trackers. The graph at the bottom of your image are not coordinates in 3d space at all. They are the speed at which the particular tracked element is moving in x and y.

Comment: @Justin yes, we want a list of x,y,z locations for every time frame for the object... we previously went to file -> export which allows you to get certain files like the ones I mentioned. Seems like the data does not match the 3D position of the object.

Comment: @cegaton that's good to know. thank you for the info. can you offer any input on how exactly to do that?

Comment: It would help if you [edit] your post (don't use comments, add to the original question https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXFuK.png) and explain what you are doing. Are you tracking an element from a video or where exactly is the tracking information coming from. Please note that nowhere in your question you mentioned that.